# Errors on play console after migrating to androidx:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

Tags: android

I´ve migrated my app to androidx following the documentation steps. I haven´t changed my app code, only imports and classes required for migration. The play console shows the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3567)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:236)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1795)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7032)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (AppComponentFactory.java:84)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (CoreComponentFactory.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3560)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:236)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1795)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7032)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

This error happens on Android 9 devices. Before updating any error was shown.

I´ve checked the code, invalidated caches and restart, switched off Instant Run and installed the latest android updates but unfortunately, as android emulator nor android 8 and 9 physical devices show no error, I only have the information provided by play console and the error remains.

This is my build.grade

```
compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.mtoh.recetasmonsieurcuisine"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 4
        versionName '1.0.4'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
           // useProguard false // <-- disable proguard
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
```

Any suggestion?

I´m thinking of reverting the migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.  If you are using AdMob, see their updated implementation instructions:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#example_app-level_buildgradle_excerpt

You have to add the following two lines to your build.gradle when using Admob 18.0.0 with AndroidX:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:17.0.0
```